# What does mean 10.D00 in Fortran?

Tags: fortran

I have to convert some code from Fortran so doesn't know how what this statement means:

```
var1 = 10.D00
```

Can someone explain me what it means?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's just 10.0 in scientific notation with double precision (that's what the D stands for).

See: http://www.fortran.com/F77_std/rjcnf0001-sh-4.html#sh-4.2.1:

---

*4.5.1 Double Precision Exponent.*

*The form of a double precision exponent is the letter D followed by an optionally signed integer constant. A double precision exponent denotes a power of ten. Note that the form and interpretation of a double precision exponent are identical to those of a real exponent, except that the letter D is used instead of the letter E.*

---

Comment: Why there are two zeros after D? Is that same like there was just one zero number?

Comment: @Иван: the number of digits is not signficant - its common in FORTRAN programs to use a 2 digit exponent though